# how many bits is the input in the Control logic in MIPS architecture?

Tags: mips

I think it would be 32-bits because the instruction is 32 bit machine code. Is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the controller, whether this is single cycle datapath or pipelined which requires more control, but for a simple single cycle data path the 32 bit input to the controller should be more than enough